# How to get SSAS to Use More Memory

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, visual-studio-2015, ssas, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to process a cube on a development server which is processing data from a different server. The process took a long time to run the first time so I figured it was partially because the development server only had 4 GB of RAM on it. So, I bumped it up to 20 GB of RAM hoping to see some improvement in performance.

However, when I checked "perfmon" I noticed that total memory usage would not go beyond 4 GB of RAM even though I now have 20 GB.

**How do I get SSAS do use more RAM?**

Something else I should do after installing RAM? I know it's recognized and the computer as a whole is actually working better.

Some info:

1. SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
2. Windows version: Windows 7 pro 64-bit
3. Visual Studio version: Community 2015

Here's a screen shot of the memory usage. At this time, the current step it's running is "*Processing Partition 'MyCube' - In Progress - 450000 of 100.*"

[image]

Here's a screen shot of the SSAS Server settings:

[image]